# Форматирование текста с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. У меня есть `div`, в который вложены дочерние `div` с данными. Я считываю эти данные с помощью `родительскийDiv.innerText` и сохраняю в файл. Как мне отформатировать текст который получается после `innerText`? Я хочу видеть в сохраненном файле что-то вроде:

```
time: 12:35;
value: 25;
name: Vasya;
```

Входные данные, условно:

```
 <div class="dataConteiner">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="date"></p>
        <p class="time"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="name"></p>
        <p class="value"></p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: поделитесь входными данными

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let jin = document.querySelectorAll('.dataConteiner');

let jout = [...jin].map( e => { // стрелочная функция. То же, что и function (e) { ...
  return {
    date: e.querySelector('.date').textContent,
    time: e.querySelector('.time').textContent,
    name: e.querySelector('.name').textContent,
    value: e.querySelector('.value').textContent,
  }
});

console.log( jout );
```

```html
<div class="dataConteiner">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="date">09/12/2050</p>
    <p class="time">13:40</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="name">Bubu</p>
    <p class="value">100500</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dataConteiner">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="date">99/99/2099</p>
    <p class="time">15:31</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="name">Moo</p>
    <p class="value">7000</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`[...]` — spread оператор. Полученные элементы добавляет в массив. 

А про метод `.map()` подробно описано в 5.5 пункте → http://learn.javascript.ru/

P.s. предполагается, что внутри каждого полученного блока гарантированно есть элементы с указанными классами. Иначе придется добавить доп. условия, чтобы не было ошибок)

P.s.-2 у вас в одном месте container, в другом conteiner — из-за такой мелочи где-то наткнетесь на ошибку)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Писал код прям тут в редакторе, опечатался)